# Сохранить состояние TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

Можно ли сохранить состояние (раскрытые узлы, SelectedItem) TreeView при смене DataContext.

Структура DataContext при смене не изменяется.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vm:NodeVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" MinWidth="80"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>        
</TreeView>
```

VM:

```
public class NodeVM : BaseVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public List<NodeVM> Childs { get; set; }

    public NodeVM()
    {
        Childs = new List<NodeVM>();
    }

    string _value;
}

public List<NodeVM> Fields { get; set; }
```

---

По советам из комментариев сделал замену того узла который меняется, но состояние дочерних узлов так не сохраняется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если у вас структура остается прежней, зачем меняете целиком весь контекст?

Comment: @Андрей, структура заполняется динамически один раз, затем обновляется. Как она заполнится вариантов очень много.

Comment: Нужно же где то хранить состояние IsExpanded  для узла. Узлы пересоздаются, а значит вам нужно обеспечить сохранение и восстановления этого значения при смене вьюмоделей. Либо завести IsExpanded во вьюмодели и переносить из старого дерева вьюмоделей в новое значение этого поля. Или использовать сторонний менеджер для хранения, что проще.

Comment: @Gardes, вы не ответили на вопрос. Замените тип коллекции на `ObservableCollection` и добавляйте/удаляйте элементы, не нужно менять контекст целиком. Состояние сохраняется: https://imgur.com/vq2Cb5E

Comment: @Андрей, можете код в ответе выложить? я задам пару уточняющих вопросов)

Comment: @Gardes, мой код - я заменил ваши `List` на `ObservableCollection`

Comment: @Андрей, окей. Допустим мне нужно заменить узел где-то в середине дерева, я его меняю(состояние этого узла - ок), а состояние дочерних узлов этого узла сброситься как понимаю.

Comment: @Gardes, да нет, вроде: https://imgur.com/8xP7T1G

Comment: @Gardes, ах, вы о другом. Дочерние узлы... Вы имеете ввиду что-то вроде перетаскивания? Есть узел и него иерархия дочерних, вы его перетаскиваете и хотите чтобы дочерние были раскрыты так же как и до перетаскивания?

Comment: @Андрей, нет, только при смене данных узла. Я в данный момент пробую то что вы посоветовали

Comment: @Gardes, кстати в пределах одной ветки это тоже работает: https://imgur.com/T1FJMjB Если уж перемещать узел в другую ветку, т.е. удалять из одной коллекции и вставлять в другую - здесь, да, состояние дочерних не сохранится

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65064/discussion-between-gardes-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема прояснилась - при обновлении автору приходит некий список, на основе которого автор строит дерево и выводит его целиком, естественно состояние в этом случае не сохранится. Тут есть 2 выхода - либо сохранять состояние отдельно и перезаписывать его в новое дерево, либо не пересоздавать объекты заново, а изменять существующие. Оба варианта не идеальны. Я приведу решение для второго.

Оба варианта потребуют различать элементы друг от друга, например, по Id, поэтому я добавлю такое свойство в `NodeVm`, также так как мы будем менять существующие объекты, то нужно вместо List использовать `ObservableCollection<T>`, чтобы GUI обновлялся автоматически, ну и не забыть вызвать `RaisePropertyChanged()` для свойств, которые могут меняться.

Теперь небольшое изменение, которое позволит упростить код, вместо корневого списка `List<NodeVM> Fields` я предлагаю завести полноценный корневой элемент `NodeVm RootNode` с некоторым уникальным ключом, у меня это будет `id=0`, все элементы, которые должны быть на верхнем уровне (`ParentId=null`), мы будем помещать в этот корневой элемент. А чтобы представление оставалось прежним, просто изменим немного привязку: `<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootNode.Childs}">`

Также, я предлагаю завести словарь `Dictionary<int, NodeVm> nodesDict`, для того чтобы было проще искать нужный узел и вносить в него изменения.

Итак, пусть к нам приходит некая коллекция элементов `List<Node> nodes`, где:

```
public class Node
{
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда, первоначальная загрузка у меня выглядит так:

```
List<Node> nodes = ...;
nodesDict = new Dictionary<int, NodeVm> { [0] = RootNode };
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    var nodeVm = new NodeVm
    {
        Id = node.id,
        Name = node.Name,
        // остальные свойства
    };
    nodesDict.Add(node.Id, nodeVm);
    // Обратите внимание, чтобы это работало необходимо,
    //  чтобы родительские элементы были в списке раньше чем дочерние,
    //  возможно потребуется их как-то сортировать (может по id)
    nodesDict[node.ParentId ?? 0].Childs.Add(nodeVm);
}
```

Теперь, при обновлении:

```
void Refresh()
{
    List<Node> nodes = ...;
    // Заводим новый словарь, чтобы знать какие элементы были удалены
    var nodesNewDict = new Dictionary<int, NodeVm> { [0] = RootNode };
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        // Если в нашем словаре есть элемент с этим Id, то берем его,
        //  иначе создаем новый
        var nodeVm = nodesDict.ContainsKey(node.Id) ? nodesDict[node.Id]
                                                    : new NodeVm { Id = node.Id };
        nodeVm.Name = node.Name;
        // остальные свойства
        nodesNewDict.Add(node.Id, nodeVm);
        // Проверка, не изменился ли родитель, либо это новый элемент
        var c = nodesDict[node.ParentId ?? 0].Childs;
        if (!c.Contains(nodeVm))
        {
            // Если изменился - находим старого (если он есть) и удаляемся из него
            nodesDict.Values.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Childs.Contains(nodeVm))?.Childs.Remove(nodeVm);
            // Добавляемся к новому
            c.Add(nodeVm);
        }
    }
    // Теперь берем все узлы, которые были раньше, но теперь их нет
    var missingKeys = nodesDict.Keys.Except(nodesNewDict.Keys).ToList();
    foreach (var key in missingKeys)
    {
        var missingNodeVm = nodesDict[key];
        // Ищем их родителя и удаляем из него
        nodesDict.Values.Single(n => n.Childs.Contains(missingNodeVm)).Childs.Remove(missingNodeVm);
    }
    // Подменяем словарь
    nodesDict = nodesNewDict;
}
```

Все. Минус этого способа - если в `Node` будут добавляться новые свойства, нужно будет не забыть добавить код для их копирования. Сейчас это делается в двух местах, но можно (и нужно) вынести в отдельный метод.